# How to load configuration from created object

Tags: c#, .net-core, configurationmanager

I have this code, which loads config from a file:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json", true, true)
                })
```

But I want to load configuration from already created object for test purposes. Something like this:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.Load(serviceOptions)
                })
```

And then I will use this configuration in Startup file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MemoryConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#memory-configuration-provider) to load configuration from an in-memory object.  E.g.

```cs
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddInMemoryCollection(
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Option1", serviceOptions.option1 },
                { "Option2", serviceOptions.option2 },
                { "Option3", serviceOptions.option3 },
            }
        );
    });
```